# how to use a variable in grepl function within a loop-R

Tags: r, loops, variables

I am new to R and, have some problems with looping and grepl functions
I have a data from like:

```
str(peptidesFilter)
  'data.frame':   78389 obs. of  130 variables:
 $ Sequence                      : chr  "AAAAAIGGR" "AAAAAIGGRPNYYGNEGGR" "AAAAASSNPGGGPEMVR" "AAAAAVGGR" ...
 $ First.amino.acid              : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ Protein.group.IDs             : chr  "1" "1;2;4" "2;5 "3" "4;80" ...
```

I want to filter the data according to $ Protein.group.IDs by using grepl function below

```
    peptidesFilter.new <- peptidesFilter[grepl('(^|;)2($|;)',
peptidesFilter$Protein.group.IDs),]
```

I want to do it with a loop for every individual data ( e.g 1, 2, 3, etc...)
and re-write name of data frame containing variable peptidesFilter.i

```
   i =1
   while( i <= N) { peptidesFilter.[[i]] <- 
   peptidesFilter[grepl('(^|;)i($|;)',
   peptidesFilter$Protein.group.IDs),] 
    i=i+1 }
```

i have two problems, 
main one i in the grep1 function does not recognized as a variable and how i can re-name filtered data in a way it will contain variable.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For grepl problem you can use `paste0` for example:

```
paste0('(^|;)',i,'($|;)')
```

For the loop , you can so something like this :

```
ll <- lapply(seq(1:4),function(x)
         peptidesFilter[grepl(paste0('(^|;)',x,'($|;)'),
                           peptidesFilter$Protein.group.IDs),])
```

then you can transform it  to a data.frame:

```
do.call(rbind,ll)

            Sequence First.amino.acid Protein.group.IDs
1            AAAAAIGGR                A                 1
2  AAAAAIGGRPNYYGNEGGR                A             1;2;4
21 AAAAAIGGRPNYYGNEGGR                A             1;2;4
3    AAAAASSNPGGGPEMVR                A               2;5
4            AAAAAVGGR                A                 3
22 AAAAAIGGRPNYYGNEGGR                A             1;2;4
```

Comment: thanks alot! paste0('(^|;)',i,'($|;)') solves the grep1 problem, what i couldnt understand lapply, basically i want to split the data based on IDs, then further process each splitted data. for example the seqeunce info. do.call(rbind,ll), it combined all the data again. is it possible to create individual data frame(such as peptidesFilterx1, peptidesFilterx2 etc..) when x=1, x=2 etc... or do i understood you wrong ?

Comment: @Samir the list ll is what you want I think.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out now. Thanks alot